# [android]DrawerLayout not completely closed effect

Tags: android, animation, navigation-drawer

I want to make the drawer layout not close completely, is there any way to obtain that ?Something like in the picture below.

Thanks, Adrian

[image]

Comment: looks like the icon is on the left but the drawer is coming out from the right